# how do i shuffle an array of numbers using python. A number is only allowed to move a step from its origin position

Tags: python

How do i get this code to shuffle the array by moving numbers only one step from its original position. The code shuffles quite alright but it shuffles numbers more than a step from its original position?

```
import random
def _shuffle_list_values():
    ids_list = [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]
    random_movements = {}
    for n_id in ids_list:
        movement = random.randrange(0,2)
        if movement == 0:
            movement-=1
        random_movements[n_id] = movement
        print(movement)
    left = -1
    right = 1
    shuffled_list = [x for x in ids_list]

    for n_id in ids_list:

        if not(ids_list.index(n_id) == 0 and random_movements[n_id] == left) or\
            not(ids_list.index(n_id) == len(ids_list) - 1 and random_movements[n_id] ==
            right):
              shuffled_list.insert(ids_list.index(n_id) + random_movements[n_id],
              shuffled_list.pop(ids_list.index(n_id)))

    return shuffled_list
```

Comment: Please do not post image of the code

Comment: Can you post the code here rather than the image?

Comment: Hi @texplode.  As is, this question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow.  Please post your actual code, instead of just a picture of it.  Then describe what you are trying to do, and what the problem is.  State what you've tried, and what you need help with.  But please begin by reading our documentation on how to ask questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it recursively like this:

```
import random

def shuffle_list(l, idx=0):

    # Base case:
    # when reached final element of the list,
    # there is nothing to flip, so return. 
    if idx >= len(l) - 1:
        return

    # flip will be either 0 or 1
    flip = random.randrange(0,2)

    if flip:
        # if flip is 1, then flip elements at position idx and idx + 1
        # then recursively call for position idx + 2 , 
        # since prev two elements are already flipped.

        l[idx], l[idx + 1] = l[idx + 1], l[idx]
        shuffle_list(l, idx + 2)
    else:
        # if flip is 0, then element at idx position remains untouched.
        # so, recursively call for idx + 1 position. 
        shuffle_list(l, idx + 1)

ll = [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]
shuffle_list(ll)
print(ll)
# [22, 21, 24, 23, 26, 25, 27, 28]
```

Or you could do it iteratively like this:

```
import random

def shuffle_list(l):
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(l) - 1:
        # For an equal distribution on the shuffle,
        # make flip choose from -1 to 1 when idx = 0
        # where -1: move left, 0: stay as it is, 1: move right
        # so, it has 1/3 possibility of moving right,
        # and in turn, second element has 1/3 possibility of moving left.
        # and it follows for subsequent elements.
        # Note that for idx = 0, there is no space on left to move,
        # so, it only moves when flip == 1
        if idx == 0:
            flip = random.randrange(-1, 2)
        else:
            flip = random.randrange(0, 2)
        if flip == 1:
            l[idx], l[idx + 1] = l[idx + 1], l[idx]
            idx += 2
        else:
            idx += 1

ll = [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]
shuffle_list(ll)
print(ll)
# [22, 21, 24, 23, 26, 25, 27, 28]
```

Result may change every time due to random flip, but will follow the rule.

Logic:

```
1. For every element i, decide if we want to flip it or not.
    a. If yes, flip element i with i+1, and repeat step 1 for element i+2.
    b. If no, skip element i, and repeat step 1 for element i+1
2. Do this until you reach at the end of the list.
```

**UPDATE:**

As per Martijn's comment, the original approach didn't have an equal distribution on the shuffle, so updated the flip decision (in the iterative version) to solve it.

Test:

```
nums = 6
position = {i:{'left':0, 'no-change':0, 'right':0} for i in range(nums)}
for i in range(10000):
    ll = list(range(nums))
    shuffle_list(ll)
    for i in range(nums):
        if i - 1 >= 0 and ll[i-1] == i:
            position[i]['left'] += 1
        elif ll[i] == i:
            position[i]['no-change'] += 1
        elif ll[i + 1] == i:
            position[i]['right'] += 1
for d in position.items():
    print(d)
```

Test output:

```
(0, {'left': 0, 'no-change': 6739, 'right': 3261})
(1, {'left': 3261, 'no-change': 3354, 'right': 3385})
(2, {'left': 3385, 'no-change': 3333, 'right': 3282})
(3, {'left': 3282, 'no-change': 3451, 'right': 3267})
(4, {'left': 3267, 'no-change': 3408, 'right': 3325})
(5, {'left': 3325, 'no-change': 6675, 'right': 0})
```

Based on a simple test over 10k iterations, it shows that all elements have roughly 1/3 possibility of moving left or right, or staying at the same position (except the first and last element which cannot move to the extreme ends.).

Comment: @texplode updated code with comments, and added a simple explanation.

Comment: Looks great, upvoted it. texplode and anyone else encountering this should however keep in mind that this doesn't have an equal distribution on the shuffle.

Comment: @Martijn Could you please explain how it doesn't have an equal distribution on the shuffle?

Comment: The second element in the array has a 50% probability to be moved to the left, and a 25% probability to move to the right or stay where it is. It's not really symmetric.

Comment: @Martijn if I would make flip = random.randrange(-1, 2) when idx = 0, that should make 2nd element's possibility to move left 1/3 and move right or stay as it is 1/3 as well. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I was considering the same option, but how would you handle the fourth element then? So what to do if 2 moved right, and 4 has to move left? If you can find a way to get that solved, you could have an equal distribution. But it won't hurt you to not have one.